# How to add crontab task by reboot / poweroff / poweron pc?

Tags: cron, init-script, autostart, hook

I have next record in `crontab -e`, running with user `root`.

```
@reboot /usr/bin/curl --silent --insecure -v -X GET https://<myserver_with_hook>?key=9d722304320de0b074d8da74bf680874&mes='nik-pc was rebooted or started!'
```

But it not work!

p.s.  if I run the command in the terminal - everything is fine. The goal is to cause a hook when you turn off / on / restart the PC.

Comment: Did the cron job not run, or did it run and error?  Are you doing anything to make sure the job waits until the network is available before it runs?  If you are using a `systemd` based distribution, `crond` would be up and running before the network is available and your `curl` command would have failed.

Comment: Thank you! I'm using systemd based distribution.